# Adding Data from predict() values to end of another plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a csv file that contains estimates of the population from 2010-2019. I've used the `predict()` function to estimate the population from 2020 to 2024. How would I combine these two plots to where 2020 starts where 2019 left off on the x- axis? Would the function ggarrange be the best option?

Also, how would I change the x-tick marks to show at 2020, 2021,2022,2023,2024? It currently just shows 1,2,3,4,5. I tried the `scale_x_discrete` function but to no avail.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

pops <- read_csv("nst-est2019-popchg2010_2019.csv")
OK_pops<- filter(pops, NAME == "Oklahoma")
pop_OK <- pivot_longer(OK_pops,
        cols=starts_with("POP"),
        names_to="Year",
        names_prefix = "POPESTIMATE",
        values_to = "Population"
)

options(digits=4)
pop_OK <- transform(pop_OK, Population=as.numeric(Population))
pop_OK <- transform(pop_OK, Year=as.numeric(Year))

str(pop_OK)

ggplot(pop_OK) + geom_point(aes(x=Year, y=Population))
abline(pop_OK)


model <-lm(formula = Population ~ Year, data = pop_OK)
summary(model)
pred <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(Year=2020:2024))
setNames(pred, 2020:2024)

plot(pred, pch = 16, col = "blue" )
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                  labels=c("2020","2021","2022","2023","2024"))
```

Comment: Adding a reproducible example dataset would be helpful, and will stop people getting snarky with you :) If your predict output has the same column names you should be able to use rbind to join them together. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321433/plotting-geom-line-and-geom-point-data-of-different-lengths this link has a solution to plotting data of different lengths which might help if you keep original and output separate :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look at how to add a reproducible example and will also check out the link! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use rbind similar to this:

new_data <- rbind(pop_ok, pred$fit)

You need to realize that the predict function has three columns of fit, lwr (lower) and upr (upper) as output. If you grab the fit column then you are loosing the upper and lower confidence intervals.

Hope this helps.